# Can a URL be defined as a Pointer?

Tags: pointers, url

I need some clarification on whether a URL counts as a pointer.

I know it's common to say that it points somewhere on the web, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) it says it needs to point/reference a location to **computer memory**. (Such as a variable)

Will someone yell at me if I call a URL a pointer?

Or is wikipedia being too specific about it and a pointer can generally be accepted as any kind of reference?

(I mean technically the servers file/web need to put it in memory to serve it right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you make it clear, by context, that you are not referring to a C pointer, I think it would be fine to say that a URL is a "pointer to a server". In an informal setting, at least. However, it would be an error to say that a URL is a pointer in a programming sense. The fact that a program might reference a URL via a variable pointer is completely irrelevant when you are describing what a URL *is*.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. : )